# To be about; to be all about

Tags: prepositions, phrasing

I have a nagging feeling "to be all about" is vastly different than its "all"-less counterpart.

> This game is all about teamwork.

To me this means the very basis, the fundamental element of this game is working together. It's basically impossible for me to say here *This game is about teamwork*.

> This book is about biology.
>
> This book is all about biology.

Here is where I start losing touch with grammatical reality. In theory, if my hypothesis is correct, the latter means the book discusses to a profound extent what biology is, its different fields, etc.

However, the former phrase doesn't truly lend itself to much meaning at all, in my opinion. I almost want to ask "Biology of *what*, exactly?"

So is there a big difference? Or am I making much ado about nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been digging through about half a dozen dictionaries and it seems that the case of **all about** is clearer than the one of **about**.

Dictionaries that list this phrase (ODO, The Online Slang Dictionary) say that it is informal or slang.

The [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be-all-about-%E2%80%94%E2%80%94) definition:

> **be all about**
>
> *informal* Be focused on or interested in (a particular thing):

[The Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/be-all-about):

> - to devote a significant amount of one's time too.
> - to be extremely enthusiastic for.

ODO gives examples related to people *someone is all about something* and definitions of the Online slang dictionary also imply that this phrase is used when referring to people. However, since the use is informal, if the definitions are taken broadly one could argue that:

> *This book **is all about** biology.*

means that the book is **focused on** biology or it **devotes significant amount of its space** (instead of time) to biology.

---

The informal use is probably the reason why in print "the book is all about" is much rarer than "the book is about" as this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=book+is+about%2Cbook+is+all+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbook%20is%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbook%20is%20all%20about%3B%2Cc0) shows.

---

As for the word **about**, as a preposition:

One of [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/about) definitions:

> On the subject of; concerning:
>
> *a book about ancient Greece*

Synonyms:

> regarding, concerning, with reference to, referring to, with regard to, with respect to, respecting, relating to, on, touching on, dealing with, relevant to, with relevance to, connected with, in connection with, on the subject of, in the matter of, apropos, re;

This would mean that

> *This book **is about** biology.*

means that **the subject of the book** is biology.

Definitions in many other dictionaries ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about), [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/about_1), [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/about) concur with this).

Case closed? Not quite... In [How to Read a Book](https://books.google.rs/books?id=Z5PpkQadm5EC&pg=PA76&dq=%22book+is+about%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-SNSVevmAqL4ywOQsIGQDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22book%20is%20about%22&f=false) by Mortimer J. Adler, Charles Van Doren the authors discuss two possible meanings of *the book is about*:

> *To say what the whole book is about is not the same as saying what kind of book it is. [...] The word "about" may be misleading here. In one sense, a book is **about** a certain type of subject matter, which it treats in a certain way. If you know this, you know what **kind** of book it is. But there is another, more colloquial sense of "about". We ask a person what he is about, what he is up to. So we can wonder what an author is up to, what he is trying to do. To find out what a book is about in this sense is to discover its **theme** or **main point**.*

So, according to this, *book is about biology* can mean:

- formal: the type/subject - it is a biology book
- colloquial: the main theme/focus of the book is biology

But in this particular example the difference is more of a nuance in meaning.

Not to restrict this answer solely to what books are (all) about, it is interesting to note that [The American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=about) warns that in informal context the usage of *about* can be broader:

> ***Usage Note:** The preposition about is traditionally used to refer to the relation between a narrative and its subject: a book about Cézanne; a movie about the Boston Massacre. For some time, this usage has been extended beyond narratives to refer to the relation between various kinds of nouns and the things they entail or make manifest: The party was mostly about showing off their new offices. You don't understand what the women's movement is about. This controversial usage probably originates with the familiar expression all about, as in Let me tell you all about her. In our 2001 survey, 62 percent of the Usage Panel rejected about in the party example listed above, and 51 percent rejected Their business is about matching people with the right technology. In 1988, 59 percent rejected a similar example. It is probably best to limit this use of about to more informal contexts.*